# Looking to Replace a 32 Watt T8 Fluorescent Bulb in an Office: What Are My Options?

Tags: lighting

I'm looking to replace a 32 Watt T8 fluorescent bulb in my home office.

I noticed that the old bulb was a Philips 32T8/COOL WHITE PLUS, while the replacement bulb that I picked up at Home Depot was a 32T8/COOL WHITE **(not PLUS)**.

It seems like the COOL WHITE PLUS bulb was white, while the regular COOL WHITE is yellowish. [I prefer white.]

My Question:

> If I want to install the best lighting for readability, which bulb should I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulbs that give off light closest to the spectrum of daylight seem to be the choice for reading by.

From your description the "plus" aspect of the original bulb adds in light to the blue end of the spectrum.